# Why is my Azure website completely blank?

Tags: azure

nutshell: **How can I debug an azure website?**

I'm at a loss. I've been changing and re-publishing an MVC asp net core site on and off for a while, publishing always works fine.

Today, I've been messing with codeFirst migrations etc. and have published my site again - which works completely fine in VS in any environment - but in Azure it's just empty space.

The azure troubleshooting says "everything's fine", but it's clearly not - where do I begin? Or do I just revert all my changes and see which branches break the site?

Comment: So instead of seeing the page you normally see, you see no page? Does the URL look correct? Anything in the F12 console? Have you gone through the guide on using logging? https://stackify.com/azure-app-service-log-files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to do is turn on debugging and look at the logs. You can enable debugging in the portal and turn on various options.

Once you have that setup, if you go to the "development tools" section in the portal and then click on "Advanced Tools (Kudu), this will take you to the backend view of your web app. In the drop-down at the top select "debug console" then either CMD or PowerShell, and you will be presented with a way to browse the content of your app. If you look in the "LogFiles" folder you will see logs that may have useful information.